# Deselect elements of a named character vector

Tags: r

I have a named character vector:

```
dat <- c("1" = 0, "2" = 0, "3" = 1)
```

I know that to select a single element I would use the following syntax:

```
dat[["1"]]
```

However, I can't figure out how to deselect, i.e. select all but one:

```
dat[[-"3"]]
```

Can anyone tell me how I would do this?

Comment: `dat[names(dat)!="3"]` would work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can also do

```
dat[!names(dat) %in% "3"]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `setdiff` :

```
remove_x <- function(vec, x) {
  vec[setdiff(names(vec), x)]
}

remove_x(dat, "1")
#2 3 
#0 1 

remove_x(dat, "3")
#1 2 
#0 0
```

You can also drop multiple values :

```
remove_x(dat, c("1", "3"))

#2 
#0
```